# ¿Cómo unir dataTable con el metodo Merge en C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Un gusto saludarles estimados.

Vengo con un inconveniente, estoy queriendo unir dos datatables.

Utilizo el metodo Merge()

dt.Merge(dt1)

El problema es que no me los agrega en el orden que deseo.

Les adjunto un print.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los dataTable que deseo unir son de 3 filas x 3columnas

Y deseo obtener uno de 3 filas X 6 columnas, pero el merge me esta generando uno de 6x6

Les adjunto el codigo que uso.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataTable n1 = new DataTable();
            n1 = CargarTabla();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = n1;

            DataTable n2 = new DataTable();
            n2 = CargarTabla2();

            dataGridView2.DataSource = n2;



            DataTable dtCombined = new DataTable();
            dtCombined = n1.Copy();
            dtCombined.Merge(n2);

            dataGridView3.DataSource = dtCombined;

        }
        private DataTable CargarTabla()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Id");
            dt.Columns.Add("Nombre");
            dt.Columns.Add("Cargo");

            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Id"] = 1;
            row["Nombre"] = "Andres";
            row["Cargo"] = "Developer";
            dt.Rows.Add(row);

            row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Id"] = 2;
            row["Nombre"] = "Federico";
            row["Cargo"] = "PM";
            dt.Rows.Add(row);

            row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Id"] = 3;
            row["Nombre"] = "Leonardo";
            row["Cargo"] = "Developer";
            dt.Rows.Add(row);

            return dt;

        }
        private DataTable CargarTabla2()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Numero");
            dt.Columns.Add("Animal");
            dt.Columns.Add("Raza");

            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Numero"] = 1;
            row["Animal"] = "Perro";
            row["Raza"] = "Bulldog";
            dt.Rows.Add(row);

            row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Numero"] = 2;
            row["Animal"] = "Perico";
            row["Raza"] = "Amazonas";
            dt.Rows.Add(row);

            row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Numero"] = 3;
            row["Animal"] = "Tigre";
            row["Raza"] = "Salvaje";
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
            return dt;

        }

    }
}
```

Edit:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
La salida esperada es: El recuadro que marco en rojo deberia de estar donde esta el recuadro verde.

No hay relacion de nada, solo son dos datables que obtengo de diferentes DataSources y quisiera unirlos en uno solo.

Ejm;

Tabla 1

```
Nombre    Apellido

Luis      Alvarez

Pedro     Escamilla
```

Tabla 2

```
RTN

123123

123123
```

Tabla 3  (Resultado esperado)

```
Nombre   Apellido     RTN

Luis     Alvarez      123123
Pedro    Escamilla    123123
```

Cabe resaltar que puede ser cualquier cantidad de columnas en cada uno de los DataTables

Comment: usa linq y haz un join IEnumerable<DataRow> merge=
    from datos1 in tabla1.AsEnumerable() join ...
    select new {id=tabla1.id,...}

Comment: Esto sucede porque la estructura de la tabla es diferente al menos en el nombre de las columnas

Comment: @LuisCarlosDonadoAvella Intenté hacerlas de la misma estructura. Pero la salida es un dataTable de 6 filas y solamente 3 columnas.

Comment: @MiguelZarate No me queda claro que debo de hacer.

Comment: No le puse atencion a tus datos, primero que resultado esperas, cuando haces una mescla debes tener al menos una columna que los relacione para ejemplo, agregas a la primer tabla mascota id y a cada persona le agregas una mascota.

Comment: ¿lo que se pretende hacer es una especie de inner join? como se relacionan las dos tablas? cual es la salida esperada?